# Redux Reducer Design

Tags: reactjs, redux

When working on Redux projects I have seen similar issues appear stemming from developers making the decision to model their reducers/data with UI components in-mind instead of thinking of the data in isolation (like you would when designing a database).

Q1. We have a UI involving a number of nouns/'things' (tracks, playlists, users...). How would you design your reducers for these? A separate reducer for each? Put them all in a single 'entity' reducer? Or some other reducer design not directly associating with the nouns of the system?

Q2. A UI has two components: an Explorer Component and a Sidebar Component. The Explorer loads in lists of items and has some options (via dropdown/modal/...) for each to edit some of the properties. You can load an item into the Sidebar which has extended options for editing properties.

An item is tagged with '#summer' via one of the components (sends a http request, returns successfully). What reducer(s) and action creator(s) would be involved/dispatched to ensure that the Components reflect this update?

Answer (score 2):

Q1: Create separate reducer where it makes sense, that is Tracks, Playlists, Users, then use something like `combineReducers` to put them all together. Don't model your store with component tree in mind, it has nothing to do with it.

Q2: You would have a collection of items in store, every item has its ID. Then you have a separate key in your store, holding only the ID of currently selected component in your sidebar. The explorer component dispatches action, something like `SET_SIDEBAR_ITEM_ID`, having an id of desired item. Sidebar component is subscribed to the store, it looks for `store.sidebar_item_id` and when it finds one, it takes the item from the store, something like `store.collection.find(item => item.id === selectedId)` and passes it as a prop to the Sidebar component.

When it comes to your last question, components will not reflect anything, they only need to take their props from the store (via the `connect` decorator). As soon as the store has correct data, React should take care of updating components for you.

Answer (score 1):

How do we decide what reducer to make?

What are the different variables or pieces of state in your application? What are the different pieces of data?

Lets take tracks, I am guessing these are musical tracks, you didn't say. So I will go with musical tracks.

So you would have a list of musical tracks and a currently selected track. The currently selected track is the one with more details for the user.

Lets keep it simple and say you only have tracks, no playlists, users, etc.

So then in this case you only have two pieces of state, the **Track Reducer** and the **Selection Reducer**.

The **Track Reducer** will be responsible for showing our list of tracks to the user. So it will be an array of objects where each object is a distinct array to show to the user and it will have properties like id of the track and probably a description of the track.

The second reducer, that we would call the **Selection Reducer** will just keep track of what the currently selected track is.

It will have a value of 1 which means the user whats more detail of the track of id 1.

So you could **Track Reducer** and a **Selection Reducer**. One provides a list the other just keeps track of the select tracks.

So, right away I am thinking your main index.js reducer and in it you would have:

```
import { combineReducers } from ‘redux’;

export default combineReducers({
   tracks: trackReducer
});
```

I hope this at least gets you going. In the meantime as you are trying to figure this out and it seems like you are working with lists or arrays, I would start that combineReducers like so:

```
import { combineReducers } from ‘redux’;

export default combineReducers({
   tracks: () => []
});
```